# Converting cassandra blob type to string

Tags: java, cassandra, blob, cql, datastax

I have an old column family which has a column named "value" which was defined as a blob data type. This column usually holds two numbers separated with an underscore, like "421_2".

When im using the python datastax driver and execute the query, the results return with that field parsed as a string:

```
In [21]: session.execute(q)
Out[21]: 
[Row(column1=4776015, value='145_0'),
 Row(column1=4891778, value='114_0'),
 Row(column1=4891780, value='195_0'),
 Row(column1=4893662, value='105_0'),
 Row(column1=4893664, value='115_0'),
 Row(column1=4898493, value='168_0'),
 Row(column1=4945162, value='148_0'),
 Row(column1=4945163, value='131_0'),
 Row(column1=4945168, value='125_0'),
 Row(column1=4945169, value='211_0'),
 Row(column1=4998426, value='463_0')]
```

When I use the java driver I get a com.datastax.driver.core.Row object back. When I try to read the value field by, for example, `row.getString("value")` I get the expected `InvalidTypeException: Column value is of type blob`. Seems like the only way to read the field is via `row.getBytes("value")` and then I get back an `java.nio.HeapByteBuffer` object.

Problem is, I cant seem to convert this object to string in an easy fashion. Googling yielded two answers from 2012 that suggest the following:

```
String string_value = new String(result.getBytes("value"), "UTF-8");
```

But such a String constructor doesn't seems to exist anymore.
So, my questions are:

1. How do I convert HeapByteBuffer into string?
2. How come the python driver converted the blob easily and the java one did not?

Side Note:
I could debug the python driver, but currently that seems too much work for something that should be trivial. (and the fact that no one asked about it suggests Im missing something simple here..)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another easier way is to change the CQL statement.

```
select column1, blobastext(value) from YourTable where key = xxx
```

The second column would be type of String.

Comment: I like this one, but Im not sure how easy it is to incorporate it in the Java driver.. going to check.

Comment: I didnt find a way to apply a function to a selected column in the Java QueryBuilder object supplied by Datastax. Otherwise that would have been a very elegant solution.

Comment: Why don't you use `session.execute("select column, ....")` directly? If you need to use QueryBuilder, try [Selection.Selection::fcall](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/querybuilder/Select.Selection.html#fcall(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). I am very sure that blobastext works in java driver, because i used it in my production project.

Comment: Do you know how to programatically create a blob from string? the fcall is only available in selection for some reason. What If I need now to update, for example, a blob column?

Comment: @idoda it should be textAsBlob(?)

Comment: @jgmjgm , did you found any way to do it for binary characters ?

Comment: I found that strangely some python/client versions show it and some don't, though I can't remember which as at this point I've reversed engineered the binary format that was being used for my use case and made a custom client / cli faculty around that.

Answer (score 8):

You can also get direct access to the Java driver's serializers. This way you don't have to deal with low-level details, and it also works for other types.

Driver 2.0.x:

```
String s = (String)DataType.text().deserialize(byteBuffer);
```

Driver 2.1.x:

```
ProtocolVersion protocolVersion = cluster.getConfiguration().getProtocolOptions().getProtocolVersion();
String s = (String)DataType.text().deserialize(byteBuffer, protocolVersion);
```

Driver 2.2.x:

```
ProtocolVersion protocolVersion = cluster.getConfiguration().getProtocolOptions().getProtocolVersion();
String s = TypeCodec.VarcharCodec.instance.deserialize(byteBuffer, protocolVersion);
```

Comment: Great answer!  Listing out how each driver version differs will help others out a lot, too.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 I agree, elaborated answer, thanks Olivier!

Comment: Any idea if its possible to do the  TypeCodec dynamically based on what the DataType.getType() is ? I am trying to convert a library thats using this approach quite heavily to 2.2.

Comment: Any idea for 3.0.x driver? Where did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

For version 3.1.4 of the datastax java driver the following will convert a blob to a string:

```
ProtocolVersion proto = cluster.getConfiguration().getProtocolOptions().getProtocolVersion();

String deserialize = TypeCodec.varchar().deserialize(row.getBytes(i), proto);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Converting from byte buffer in Java is discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26720655/20688).

2.) Assuming you're using Python 2, it's coming back as a string in Python because str is the binary type.